# Pattern only matches once, when multiple matches are in the string

Tags: regex

I am trying to match image URLs which are enclosed in URL tags as follows

```
[URL=http://www.google.com/sdaasd/sadasda/asddsa/sadsa/dasd.html][IMG]http://www.cnn.com/asd.jpg[/IMG][/URL]
```

I have the following pattern which works perfectly when only matched against a single instance of a URL/IMG combo

```
\[URL=("|)([\s\S]*?)("|)]\[img\](https?:\/\/.*\.(?:png|jpg))\[\/img]\[\/URL\]
```

HOWEVER, If I repeat the URL/IMAGE combo as follows:

```
[URL=http://www.google.com/sdaasd/sadasda/asddsa/sadsa/dasd.html][IMG]http://www.cnn.com/asd.jpg[/IMG][/URL] [URL=http://www.google.com/sdaasd/sadasda/asddsa/sadsa/dasd.html][IMG]http://www.cnn.com/asd.jpg[/IMG][/URL]
```

Then it no longer works.  Any ideas on a workaround/fix??

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: And `("|)`, although legal, is one of the more confusing fragments I've seen. What do you hope it means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you need to modify the `.*` to use a [non-greedy quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy), `.*?`, like this:

```
\[URL=("|)([\s\S]*?)("|)]\[img\](https?:\/\/.*?\.(?:png|jpg))\[\/img]\[\/URL\]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `.*` is matching as much as possible, including `][IMG]`.  you can avoid this by excluding `]`: `[^]]*`

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix that you can do is to use a lazy quantifier instead of a greedy quantifier. In other words replace `.*` by `.*?`

You can use a more efficient pattern that avoid the lazy quantifier, example:

```
$pattern ='~\[URL=([^]]*+)]\[IMG]([^[]*+)\[/IMG]\[/URL]~';
```